# ¿Cómo usar una variable a modo de nombre de columna en una consulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta pasando el campo del `WHERE` como variable, de la siguiente forma:

```
declare @texto varchar (100)
declare @texto2 varchar (100)

set @texto = 'radicado'
set @texto2 = '5959'

SELECT * FROM tblDocumental WHERE @texto LIKE '%'+ @texto2 +'%'
```

Pero no me arroja resultados, no he podido encontrar documentación sobre si puedo pasar un `campo` como variable, a diferencia de si lo ejecuto así:

```
SELECT * FROM tblDocumental WHERE radicado LIKE '%'+ @texto2 +'%'
```

Si obtengo resultados, lo que no quiero es crear un `if` para evaluar que tipo de campo es, si no poderlo pasar por variable.

Alguien sabe si es posible o si la única opción es por `if`, muchas gracias por sus aportes

Comment: y qué pasa si el valor que le pones a la variable `@texto` no existe como columna de la tabla?. En todo caso, la forma de hacer esto es con SQL dinámico, pero te abre a posibles situaciones de [SQL injection](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL), por lo que hazlo con cuidado

Comment: @Lamak Gracias por responder, en la capa de aplicación existe una validación que revisa que elijas un campo que exista, desde los checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma intermedia a la consulta dinámica es jugar un poco con el `WHERE`, en este caso, si eventualmente hubiera más de una condición, podrías hacer algo así:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM tblDocumental 
    WHERE   1 = 2
        OR (@texto = 'radicado' AND radicado LIKE '%'+ @texto2 +'%')
        OR (@texto = 'otra_columna' AND otra_columna LIKE '%'+ @texto2 +'%')
```

El eventual problema que puedes tener con ésta y la consulta dinámica es que son complejas de optimizar para el motor.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como se te mencionó, usar variables para especificar nombres de columnas u otros objetos sólo se puede hacer por medio de SQL dinámico. El código dinámico abre la posibilidad de tener vulnerabilidades sólo si no se realiza de forma correcta. Aquí dejo un ejemplo con las 3 validaciones principales que se hacen para evitar Inyección SQL (o como se le conoce también, el problema Bobby Tables).

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

--Validamos de las vistas del sistema que la columna exista en la tabla.
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM tblDocumental WHERE ' 
            + QUOTENAME(c.name) --Protegemos el nombre para prevenir problemas con nombres inadecuados
            + N' LIKE ''%''+ @texto2 +''%'';'
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'tblDocumental'
AND c.name = @texto;

--Ejecutamos la consulta de forma parametrizada.
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@texto2 varchar (100)', @texto2;
```

Por último, debes evitar que este tipo de consultas llenen tu sistema. Se puede volver muy complicado de manejar y terminará siendo lento y propenso a errores.